# fit an image inside a div without cutting it

Tags: html, css, image

I have a problem with images and their container `div` element. My images are smaller than the container div and when I try to fit them the images are cut in the lower part. How can I fix this?

I browsed the web and find a lot of solution but I wasn't able to apply them to my work. Can you help me?

here is my code:

css:

```
#box_foto_1{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    height: 262px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


#box_foto_1 img{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

here the html/php:

```
$html .= "<div id='box_foto_1'>";
$html .= "<img src='$row[foto1]' >";
$html .= "</div> <!-- fine box_foto_1 -->";
```

the html/php code is part of a php function to create the page.

Comment: please change your css like me, see if this work 

#box_foto_1 img{
    height: auto;
    width:  auto;
}

Comment: thanks for the reply, it doesn't change, it remains like before

Comment: Well do you need images has same width the div with id box_foto_1, right ?

Comment: yes thank you, if you find a solution you really help me

Answer (score 2):

I'm replying from mobile phone so I cannot give you specific code but, if I got tight your question, the best way is to handle your image size by php.

You can do like this:

1) Remove #box_foto_1 img  from your css

2) Add some if/else to your PHP

```
    $html .= '<div ....';
    $div_height = 256;
    $div_width = 500;

    // now get your image dimensions and check whitch one is bigger

    ......

list($img_w, $img_h) = getimagesize($your_image);


    if($img_h>$img_w) {
         $html .= '<img src="' . $your_image . ' style="height: ' . $div_height .'px; width="auto" />';

    } else {
     $html .= '<img src="image.jpg" style="width: ' . $div_width .'px; height="auto" />';
    }

    $html .= '</div>';
```

Search how to get image dimensions with php...  can't help you with this now ... because i'm on phone.

You can find here how to get your image size:

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.getimagesize.php

---

Update: I added the getimagesize function.

Answer (score 1):

**IF you want the image to fit the box and display the whole image:**

All you need to do is remove your `#box_foto_1` height `height:262px` value or set this as a `min-height` or `max-height` whichever is appropriate for you.

**IF you want the image contained within the fixed size of the box:**

Remove the max-/min- values (in my now deleted previous answer) in the CSS for the size of the box and then set the width *and* height to `auto` values on the `#box_foto_1 img`. As so:

```
   #box_foto_1 {
        /* added or changed rules */
        display:block;
    }
    #box_foto_1{
        clear: both; /* Clear before float is probably useless */
        float: left;
        width: 400px;
        height: 262px;
        border: 1px solid;
        margin-left: 100px;
        margin-top: 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    #box_foto_1 img{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Setting both values to 100% will stretch the image, you need to set one as auto such as `height:auto;` which will cause width overflow.

https://jsfiddle.net/bvkurufq/3/

---

The best way of solving this in general is to set the image value as a CSS background image and then you are free for a lot more CSS manipulation of it. You can do this by defining the image inline with a `style` section at the top of your `<body>` filled with the database SRC references.

Example:
PHP/ HTML output:

```
<?php
/*within the PHP image loop */
{
<style>
    #imageUniqueId {
    background-image:url('<?php print $imageURL;?>');
    }
</style>
<div id='box_foto_1'>
<div id='imageUniqueId' class='imageClass'></div>
</div> <!-- fine box_foto_1 -->

<?php 
}
?>
```

CSS:

```
#box_foto_1{
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 262px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

.imageClass {
        display:block;
        min-width: 400px;
        min-height: 262px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: contain;
    }

See https://jsfiddle.net/bvkurufq/33/

Comment: indeed the lower part of the image is hidden and that's the lower part that I am missing in the image also with your solution.. at this point I think that there is no solution for the image to fit (upscale) inside a div..

Comment: @P.Davide the solution in using `<img>` and CSS is that either one or both of the `width`/`height` properties need to be given a set value, such as `100%` and the other an auto (inherited) value from the image entity itself.

Comment: ok thanks for the info, so I need to put in my php code the tag <img> and set value height and width. Then in CSS part I need to put height: auto and width 100% right?

Comment: does my jsfiddle work for you? to make the image into a CSS image would involve a decent amount of code reworking on the code you've shown so far. I will write a solution and add it to my answer.

Comment: thanks i tried your js fiddle but it doesn't work here.. I don't know why, I copied and pasted your code in my page but the image remains cutted in the lower part.. I don't want to bother you anymore, really, I don't know why it doesn't work..

Comment: @P.Davide I have updated my anwser to show CSS method, take a look at it.

Comment: Martin I was trying your last solution but now i have a php network error... for some reason it is not able to load the image even if in the display source code option the image path is correctly shown..

 $html .= "<style>";
 $html .= "#box_foto_1_img{";
 $html .= "background-image:url('$row[foto1])');";
 $html .= "}";
 $html .= "</style>";
 $html .= "<div id='box_foto_1'>";
 $html .= "<div id='box_foto_1_img' class='imageClass'></div>";
 $html .= "</div> <!-- fine box_foto_1 -->";

Comment: @P.Davide your `id` value for each image needs to be unique. `Id`s must always be unique. Use something like the database row ID as the style object id, appended to something like `#id_image_$phprowid`

Comment: thanks pal but i wasn't able to fix it.. sorry I give up with the problem I am not able to achieve it... :(

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvkurufq/3/) provided by Martin, so you may try something like this to contain your image inside the div without cropping or distorting the proportion:

Just add this to your image class:

```
#box_foto_1 img{
        max-width: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
        height: 100%;
        }
```

If you want to fit the image exactly the size of your div than in that case you need to specify the same dimensions as your block to the image but this will distort the proportion.

or replace `object-fit:contain` with `object-fit:fill`.

Comment: `Object-fit` looks like a wonderful bit of CSS, I never knew about that.

Comment: Yup, it is. :) A lot easier way to handle images without distorting the image ratio.

Comment: Although it is almost completely not IE known and also has safari issues. I really hate how variable browser take up and rule declarations are for web design. :-/ http://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit